# Swift & Sprite-Kit: How to rotate sprites to the direction set by collision?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to game physics. I would like to create a sprite in Sprite-kit where the sprite would rotate as it collides with screen boundaries or other objects in the game. Basically like so.

[image]

I just have no idea how this is done in Sprite-Kit or with any other framework for that matter... Do I have to calculate rotations in code or does the framework offer assistance? If this is going to be done in my code, could someone help me get started? Thanks a bunch already!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SKAction:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:5)
sprite.runAction(action)
```

This will rotate the sprite 180º

Comment: Yes but how do I know which direction should I turn the sprite? Collisions can happen from countless different angles.